# Clone the Windows partition with Carbon Copy Cloner?

Tags: backup, hard-drive, disk-utility

I have bought a new Hard Drive and I want to switch from my old disk to my new one. Time machine will do the job for my Mac partition, but not the Windows partition I guess. So I'm looking for way to transfer the content from one disk to another.

I've found the utility Carbon Copy Cloner. But I don't know if this soft is able to make a clone of the Windows formated partition (visible on my mac)

PS/ If you have another solution ...

EDIT: I just noticed that actually, Time Machine "sees" the Windows partition. Does it means that I will be able to restore it without any pain?

Comment: If it sees it, it's because OS X can read NTFS windows partitions.  It just can't write to them without 3rd party software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look into finding a copy of Winclone.  The main problem for SuperDuper and CCC is the inability to write to NTFS volumes.  They can backup your files, but often not necessarily capture the extended attributes with regards to ownership and permissions etc, resulting in an inability to make a sensible restore.

Winclone is no longer in active development, but it is effectively CCC for windows/bootcamp partitions.  I've used it to transfer bootcamp partitions from one drive to another in the past.

Comment: Actually [Winclone](http://twocanoes.com/software.php?software=1) was revived not too long ago and now fully supports both OS X 10.7 as well as Windows Vista and 7.

Answer (score 0):

There is no effective way to back up or duplicate your Windows boot partition while booted into Mac OS X.

The only effective way to back up or duplicate your Windows partition is to boot into Windows and use a Windows backup utility. There are many available, such as [Symantec Norton Ghost](http://us.norton.com/ghost).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dd` to clone the partition bit by bit. Be sure to use the `rdisk` instead of the `disk` (should be much faster).

Example:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk6s1 of=/dev/rdisk7s1
```